# Inertia redirect issue in Laravel with Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a modal in vue where I call this function

```
const  createChat = async (id) =>{
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/pdf-chat/create-chat', {
            name: name.value,
            pdfId: id,

        });
        dialogVisible.value = false;
        console.log(response)
    

    } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending message:', error);

    }
}
```

The controller function called,the route exists

```
public function createChat( Request $request)
    {
        $chat = new Chat();
        $chat->name = $request->name;
        $chat->save();


        $pdf = Upload::find($request->pdfId);


        return Inertia::location(route('pdf-chat', ['chat' => $chat->hash, 'pdf' => $pdf->hash]));
}
```

I get  a redirect 302
[image]

And the next request is the redirect url with 200 code but I stay on the same page,nothing in the browser`s url changes.
If a copy the url and paste it in the browser it works fine.
[image]

Any thoughts? Laravel 10,Vue 3 ,Inertia 1.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use (it's only for **External redirects**):

`Inertia::location()`

use:

`to_route('pdf-chat', ['chat' => $chat->hash, 'pdf' => $pdf->hash])`

Update:

I see now, because you are using **axios** you should use **inertiajs router** [inertiajs.com/manual-visits](https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits)

Comment: Tried that at first,same thing.

Comment: I see now, because you are using **axios** you should use **inertiajs router**

https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits

Comment: Edit your answer,it`s less fragile than comments.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Axios to make the request, use Inertia's `router.visit` or one of their helpers like `router.get`. These will intercept the request and know how to handle the response.

See https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits

```js
router.visit('/pdf-chat/create-chat', {
  method: 'get',
  data: {
    name: name.value,
    pdfId: id
  }
})
```